# How to Update one ID Range to Another ID Range on SQL

Tags: mysql

How to Replace an ID Range With With Another ID Range on SQL,

Table = files, Colum = drive, Range 301-400

SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE `id` BETWEEN 301 AND 400 ORDER BY `create_at` DESC

and Wanna Update All (301 - 400) to (401 - 500)

if 301 = 401, 302 = 402,

Can anyone Tell Me exact Querty to Update db

Thanks

Comment: Do SQL update, `UPDATE table SET id = id + 100 WHERE <condition>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update files 
set id = id + 100
WHERE id BETWEEN 301 AND 400
```

Comment: This works if the ranges don't overlap or you are subtracting from the ids.  If adding and there is overlap, add `order by id desc`

Comment: @ysth so it should be like : WHERE id BETWEEN 301 AND 400 order by id desc ?

Comment: If changing 301-400 to 401-500, no order by is needed.  If changing 301-500 to 401-600, it needs `order by id desc`.  If changing 401-600 to 301-500, it should have `order by id asc` but will likely work without that